# MySQL UPDATE statement times out

Tags: mysql, freeze, sql-update

The following very simple snippet of SQL is failing:

```
UPDATE smalltable,bigtable
SET smalltable.ssn=bigtable.ssn
WHERE smalltable.last = bigtable.last && smalltable.first = bigtable.first;
```

bigtable has 16,000 records -- not really all that big for SQL.  smalltable has about 300.  For some reason this statement is timing out (> 30 seconds).  Why?  It seems very simple, and the data isn't hard to work with: not a lot of repeats, short fields (VARCHAR(20)), etc.

Am I doing something wrong?  I'm just trying to update the records in smalltable with a simple (or so I thought) lookup in bigtable.

Edit: Very possibly relevant: smalltable is a `LOCAL INFILE`.

Comment: Can you post create table for smalltable and bigtable? It seems that you don't have indexes on join columns (first and last).

Comment: bigtable has lots of irrelevant records (175 in total), but the key ones are last and first which are VARCHAR(20) and ssn which is VARCHAR(16).  smalltable has exactly those three fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have indexes on:

```
smalltable.last, bigtable.last, smalltable.first, bigtable.first
```

Comment: Doh! Nuked my answer; this one's better. +1.

Comment: It wasn't my database, so I figured it was already set up with indexes, at least on the important tables like bigtable. No, it wasn't!  Now MySQL reports that it took 0.000 seconds.